# Shape of confining potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, approximations

So last time I posted a question on the same topic, but due to my bad english the question was not clear. This time I will try to be more specific and understandable.
In literature I have observed that to analyse a quantum system under the influence of spherical confining potential, the authors uses square well or parabolic potential model. My question is, wouldn't it be a better approach to use spherical potential well rather than the other two?

Answer (score 0):

The question is still not quite clear: it could be helpful to provide reference to the specific books and/or contexts where such approach is used.

For example, every quantum mechanics textbook treats motion in a Coulomb field, solving the problem in spherical coordinates (although some more exotic approaches are possible - if I am not mistaken, L&L provide also a solution in parabolic coordinates).

What is more important, is that the radial part of the spherical potential can be a square well or a harmonic oscillator
$$
V(r) = \begin{cases} -V_0,\text{ if } r<r_0\\0\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
or
$$
V(r) = \frac{m\omega^2r^2}{2}
$$
These approximations are extensively used, e.g., in nuclear physics for describing the nucleus.